# Evaluate ${n \choose 1}+2{n \choose 2}+...+n{n \choose n}$

Tags: summation, induction

I have trouble finding an explicit expression to prove this sum using induction, and would like a hint. It would also help if someone provided a non-induction question.

Comment: write down binomial theorem, stare at it.

Comment: been there, done that. I can't simplify it down to the binomial theorem or I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Hint: $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n}{k} \binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: Me thinks you haven't stared enough, you may want to include "no calculus please" in your question

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$ \binom{n}{k}k = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}k = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1} $$

For the last step, note that $n-k = (n-1)-(k-1)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

What is the derivative of $(1+x)^n$?

Comment: Um, I'd prefer to things that the eight grade me could understand. I would rather not do calculus on this problem.

Comment: Pardon me, but derivatives and Newton's formula are seen in high school, as far as I know. Now if you don't want a two-line computation, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Gerard L. When I was in 8th grade, I barely knew what exponents where (and by 12th grade most people around me barely knew what's a function contrary to Bernard's post), so you're in much, much better position to understand this than I was.